# Variance of precision in conjugate prior

Tags: normal-distribution, inference, bayes, conjugate-prior

How can I calculate the variance of the precision in a normal distribution, knowing I used a conjugate prior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conjugate prior for the precision of a normal distribution is a [Gamma distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution).  If you use this, the posterior will be a Gamma distribution.  Then you apply the known formula for the variance of a Gamma distribution (on the linked page) to get the variance of the posterior.